# Given an array of strings, return another array containing all of its longest strings. using Dart

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

Given an array of strings, return another array containing all of its longest strings.

Example

For `inputArray = ["aba", "aa", "ad", "vcd", "aba"]`, the output should be
solution(inputArray) = ["aba", "vcd", "aba"].

[execution time limit] 4 seconds (dart)

[input] array.string inputArray

[input] array.string inputArray

A non-empty array.

Guaranteed constraints:
1 ≤ inputArray.length ≤ 10,
1 ≤ inputArray[i].length ≤ 10.

[output] array.string

[output] array.string

Array of the longest strings, stored in the same order as in the inputArray.

I know that the javascript code answer of the above question but did't know how to write it into dart.
this is the javascript //

```
  var maxLength = Math.max(...inputArray.map(s => s.length));
    return inputArray.filter(s => s.length === maxLength);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `sort` the list by its item's length and then search for items that have equal length to the longest item in sorted list. like this:

```
var inputArray = ["aba", "aa", "ad", "vcd", "aba"];
inputArray.sort(
  (a, b) => b.length.compareTo(a.length),
);
var result = inputArray
    .where((element) => element.length == inputArray.first.length)
    .toList();
print("inputArray = $result"); //[aba, vcd, aba]
```

**or** use `reduce` instead of `sort`, like this:

```
var maxString = inputArray.reduce(
    (value, element) => element.length > value.length ? element : value);

var result = inputArray
    .where((element) => element.length == maxString.length)
    .toList();
print("inputArray = $result"); //[aba, vcd, aba]
```

Comment: bro can you visit this website and solve the question https://app.codesignal.com/challenge/37qGcpbFxgRZn2GZX

Comment: Don't forget to Vot.e my question borther

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy.

```
final inputArray = ["aba", "aa", "ad", "vcd", "aba"];

final lenArr = inputArray.map((e) => e.length).toList()..sort();
final finalArr = inputArray.where((el) => el.length == lenArr.last);

log(finalArr.toString()); // [aba, vcd, aba]
```

Output:

```
[aba, vcd, aba]
```

Comment: usercodemain.dart on line 7:14: Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'.
log(finalArr.toString());
             ^
usercodemain.dart on line 1:14: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'List<String>' doesn't allow null.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
List<String> solution(List<String> sequence) {

Comment: bro it give me this error what should i do

Comment: if you're using this in a method/function, you should add ``return finalArr.toList();`` at the end of function. Or add your code where you're using my solution. @M.Shahzad

Comment: @M.Shahzad, just add line 3 and 4 and then ``return finalArr.toList();`` in the solution method.

Comment: @M.Shahzad, it seems like you imported `dart:math` instead of `dath:developer`...The log function from the math library expects a number while the one from developer expects a String...You should rather import `dart:developer`

Comment: bro can you write the answer into only if-else and for condition instead of loops and flutter reserved keywords?

Comment: @M.Shahzad so what is ``for`` if it's not loop?

Comment: sir for , while, and do while is loop in programming

Comment: @M.Shahzad but you said to write answers using for condition instead of loops? Please read before what you're writing. Be clear what you want. You're making confusion.

Comment: sorry sir its is my mistake

Comment: @M.Shahzad, send message on Facebook. You can find my profile link in my stackoverflow profile.